# How to use yii2 as a backend for another application?

Tags: yii2, backend

What components should I take from the full yii2 framework if I want to use it just as a backend for my application? And which of them must be requested from the application?

I want to send requests with params and get json data from db according to these params.

Answer (score 1):

Look [REST](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) service from Yii2, its very powerfull.

Comment: Yes, but how to tune routing properly if we want to use yii2 framework only for ajax requests? When we must do initialisation of yii2 in that case? And do we need whole framework or just some part of it?

Comment: You can use `Yii2` normally and only use Ajax request normally, you dont need to serve a view, you can response data, a JSON, what you want.